# Python module prints correct value, then returns None

Tags: python-3.x, return-value, nonetype

```
if len(cur_node.members) <= 1:
    print(cur_node.members)
    member = str(cur_node.members[0])
    print(member)
    return member
```

The whole program is here: [gitlab: dicotomous_key](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1L1sAgla0MuvNfTcFUti0Vj0KcB-aDWaI)
  [1](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1L1sAgla0MuvNfTcFUti0Vj0KcB-aDWaI): https://gitlab.com/vanzippee/dicotomous_key

The program prints "cur_node.member" and "member" properly (just added to test), but the return value when printed is "None".

I hesitated to put the whole module here because of the length, but here it is. I changed a statement from the original (in the git) that called a database to one that opens a json file.

[Json file for library:](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1L1sAgla0MuvNfTcFUti0Vj0KcB-aDWaI)

Whole Module:

```
import json


class node:
    def __init__(self, members=None, criterion_index=0):
        print("new_node:", members)
        self.members = members
        self.criterion_index = criterion_index
        self.left_child = None
        self.right_child = None
        self.y = []
        self.n = []


class tree:
    def __init__(self, criteria, doc):
        self.root = None
        self.criteria = criteria
        self.doc = doc

    def insert(self, members):
        if self.root is None:
            self.root = node(members)
            self.insert(members)
        else:
            separated = self._insert(self.root, members)
            print("separated =", separated)
            return separated

    def _insert(self, cur_node, members):
        if len(cur_node.members) <= 1:
            print(cur_node.members)
            member = str(cur_node.members[0])
            print(member)
            return member
        elif cur_node.criterion_index < len(self.criteria):
            y = []
            n = []
            for member in members:
                if member in self.doc[self.criteria[cur_node.criterion_index]]:
                    y.append(member)
                else:
                    n.append(member)
            cur_node.criterion_index += 1
            if len(y) > 0 and len(n) > 0:
                if cur_node.left_child is not None:
                    cur_node = cur_node.left_child
                    self._insert(cur_node, y)
                else:
                    cur_node.left_child = node(y, 
                        cur_node.criterion_index)
                    self._insert(cur_node.left_child, 
                        cur_node.left_child.members)
            elif (len(y) == 0 and len(n) > 0 and cur_node.left_child is 
                    not None):
                if cur_node.right_child is not None:
                    cur_node = cur_node.right_child
                    self._insert(cur_node, n)
                else:
                    cur_node.rigth_child = node(n, 
                        cur_node.criterion_index)
                    self._insert(cur_node.right_child, 
                        cur_node.right_child.members)
            else:
                self._insert(cur_node, cur_node.members)

    def print_tree(self):
        if self.root is not None:
            self._print_tree(self.root)

    def _print_tree(self, cur_node):
        if cur_node is not None:
            self._print_tree(cur_node.left_child)
            if len(cur_node.members) == 1:
                print(cur_node.members, "separated.")
            self._print_tree(cur_node.right_child)


def make_dicotomous_key(user, category):
    with open('doc.json') as json_file:
        doc = json.load(json_file)
    members = doc["members"]
    criteria = doc["criteria"]
    dicotomous_key = tree(criteria, doc)
    while len(members) > 0:
        separated = dicotomous_key.insert(members)
        if separated is not None:
            print("returned", separated)
            members.remove(separated)
    dicotomous_key.print_tree()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    user = "default"
    category = "shark_faimilies"
    make_dicotomous_key(user, category)
```

Comment: [mre] - your code here returns nothing because it is not a fully specced function we could run.

Comment: Here is the whole code.

Comment: A [mcve] means it needs to be **minimal** and **reproducible** - show us the minimum amount of code needed to demonstrate the issue, and make it such that someone else can copy/paste in order to verify it. Your code depends on a file named `doc.json` so it is not reproducible.

Comment: I didn't try it but I think the issue could be that your insert method only returns something in the else case: there is no return statement in the if.

Comment: How is it not reproducible if I also provide the file? If I make it more minimal the error doesn't reproduce.

Comment: Why would the function print out the statement right before the return, then not return anything?

Comment: It might be reproducible but it is not minimal. Try testing small parts of your code until you narrow in on where the problem is (often you'll solve your own problem by doing this). Then if it still is odd behaviour that you can't find an answer to elsewhere then share that piece of code in a question.

Answer (score 0):

looks like you are doing a recursion there, I think that you should replace `self._insert` with `return self._insert`. The first if returns members but then when the function returns and gets back to one of the `self._insert` calls nothing is returned.